# Why this Latex code hangs lualatex? Foreign command \over;

Tags: amsmath, breqn

I am compiling code generated by FriCAS computer algebra system.

Would like to know if you think the Latex code generated by FriCAS is invalid, so I can complain to them, or if there is a work around.

It is small Latex code. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}[frame={.5pt}]
{{\log \left( {{{b \  x}+a}} \right)} -{\log \left( {{{b \  x} -a}} \right)}} \over {2 \  a \  b}
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it, lualatex hangs

```
>lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /home/me/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using
 read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/me/.t
exlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.126 seconds
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(load luc: /home/m
e/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/breqn.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/flexisym.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/cmbase.sym)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breqn/mathstyle.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)) (./foo.aux)

Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 8.
```

Stops here.

If I do not use `breqn` and do this

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
{{\log \left( {{{b \  x}+a}} \right)} -{\log \left( {{{b \  x} -a}} \right)}} \over {2 \  a \  b}
\]

\end{document}
```

It works now.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even though I still get the warning message, it does not hang, and it generated the PDF OK.

I'd like to use `breq`, I have no problem with it, except in this example.

Question is: Is the Latex generated by FriCAS bad latex or is there another issue here? Is there an easy work around (other than not using `breqn` ?

Comment: `\over` is a Plain TeX command, hence the warning. But it is probably not the reason why LuaLaTeX stops. A mere warning should is not supposed to hang the typesetting process.

Comment: `amsmath` definitely does give the warning, but does not hang.  so that more likely comes from `breqn`, which is known to have problems.  (although this is one i hadn't heard about.)

Comment: isn't the rrror message clear?, use `\frac` not `\over`.

Comment: why the `\ `  spaces?

Comment: As usual, the output produced by the CAS is rubbish. 

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I have no control over the output generated. This is how the program generates the Latex. I do not know why it generates spaces also. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser you always have control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal example is

```
\begin{dmath*}
a\over b
\end{dmath*}
```

Solution: dump that CAS. Alternative solution: add braces around the item and live with wrong output. The code is abundant in useless braces and misses the needed ones.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
{{{\log \left( {{{b \  x}+a}} \right)} -{\log \left( {{{b \  x} -a}} \right)}} \over {2 \  a \  b}}
\end{dmath*}

\[
\frac{\log(bx+a)-\log(bx-a)}{2ab}
\]

\end{document}
```

For my sanity, I added the correct typesetting.

[image]

Comment: What does CAS stand for?